# Python re.sub(): trying to replace escaped characters only

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

With Python 3.x, I need to replace escaped double quotes in some text with some custom pattern, leaving non-escaped double quotes as is. So I write as trivial code as:

```
text = 'These are "quotes", and these are \"escaped quotes\"'
print(re.sub(r'\"', '~', text))
```

And expect to see:

```
These are "quotes", and these are ~escaped quotes~
```

But instead of above, I get:

```
These are ~quotes~, and these are ~escaped quotes~
```

So, what't the correct pattern to replace escaped quotes only?

*Background of this issue is an attempt to read 'invalid' JSON file containing Javascript function in it, placed with line feeds as is, but with escaped quotes. If there is easier way to parse JSON with newline characters in key values, I appreciate a hint on that.*

Comment: You need to use a raw string to assign to `text`, otherwise the backslash just escapes the quote, it's not kept in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use a raw string to assign `text`, so that the backslashes will be kept literally (or you can escape the backslashes).

```
text = r'These are "quotes", and these are \"escaped quotes\"'
```

Second, you need to escape the backslash in the regexp so that it will be treated literally by the regexp engine.

```
print(re.sub(r'\\"', '~', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

using raw text might help.

```
import re

text = r'These are "quotes", and these are \"escaped quotes\"'
print(re.sub(r'\\"', '~', text))
```